# Correct lay-out 3 divs + background

Tags: css, layout

I've been trying about everything and the solution must be very simple.
What I basically want is a header that is 100% of the width of the screen.
Than 3 div's with some content in it.

The thing is, I DON'T want to use position ABSOLUTE...

And the background image should always fit the full screen. Right now I get a white space on the bottom of my page...

Hope this clears it up.

My lay-out:

```
============================================
HEADER WIDTH 100%
============================================

|======|                   |============|
| DIV A|                   |    DIV C   |
|======|                   |            |
                           |            |
|======|                   |            |
| DIV B|                   |            |
|======|                   |============|
```

Could you tell me which CSS formatting I need to use?

Comment: *I've been trying about everything* - *What* exactly did you try?

Comment: please mention the code which you tried...!!

Comment: maybe this will get you started http://jsfiddle.net/WVaea/1/

Comment: Thanks koningdavid...that's about what I meant.

The only remaining problem...in your example you have 2 div's (left + right). I want 3 div's (a + b on left side, c on right side)
Do you have an example of that?

Comment: @Nick like this? http://jsfiddle.net/WVaea/4/

Comment: Sorry koningdavid, but that wasn't working out...both your solutions gave me some issues.
Zey provided the best possible answer...

Comment: @koningdavid...I tried the solution given below, which works ok if you don't resize your browser. As you resize it...the right div dissapears. Any idea how to fix this? So the div is always there, but there will be scrollbars?

Answer (score 0):

Give the divs percentage based width values and use

```
background-size: cover;
```

in your css.

Comment: Someone else has graciously provided you with the answer.
background-size:cover; will allow the background image to cover the whole screen.

Comment: Thanks for the background-size: cover method...it fixed my background issues!

And thanks to zey my positions are fixed :D

Comment: Sorry...there's still a problem.

My site has a index.php and a secure_page.php.
I want to have a different background for both pages.

What I did was make a div indexbg and put in your solution...but somehow that doesn't work anymore. It does work in body. Any idea?
Using position absolute on #indexbg works...but will give me new errors.

Comment: Your question was how to fit a background image to the full width of the screen. My answer told you how. 

You shouldn't need another div, you can apply the background image to the body element. Give the body elements on both pages different classes, and give each class a different background image.

Comment: Ahh, new user. Not to worry.

Comment: P.s. do you happen to know how to fix the problem that the right div dissapears?

Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fwZbb/
Now if you make your browser less wide, the right div dissapears. Any idea how to fix this so the div is still visible but you need to scroll horizontal to see the right div?

Comment: If you give the overall layout a min-width:  ; it will stop the layout being fluid.

Comment: Hmm ok, it works if I set it to 1200px or higher.
I already had min-width 1024px...but perhaps the different elements were bigger.

Thanks again

Comment: I just tried it on my Galaxy S3...
Background is working fine in default browser, but only the header is being shown.

On mobile chrome browser the background is only the screensize of my phone. As soon as I scroll the rest is blank :((

Comment: Hi Nick. Not trying to be critical, but this has deviated quite a lot from your original question. If you keep extending the things you need help with it becomes frustrating for anyone trying to help you. The answers given already should cover this question in desktop browsers. As far as mobile browsers are concerned, you should either open new questions, or search to see if they've been asked already. (They probably have).

Comment: For future reference, Stackoverflow is not a 'help' site, it's a question & answer site.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here it is , [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fwZbb/) !

### html

```
    <div class="header">Your Header</div><br/><br/>
    <div class="left">
    <div class="leftUpper"></div><br/>
    <div class="leftLower"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
```

### css

```
body {
background: url(http://www.hdwallpapersarena.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10  
/abstract_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
  padding:20px;
 }

 .header
  {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-color:Black;
  text-align:center;
  color:White;

   }

.left
 {
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:200px;

float:left;    
padding:5px;
 }

.right
{position:relative;
width:100px;
    height:200px;
background-color:Lime;
 float:right;   
 }

.leftUpper
   {
width:100%;
height:80px;
background-color:Black;

   }

 .leftLower
  {
    width:100%;
height:80px;
background-color:Black;
bottom:0;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry...still an issue.
When I change the Chrome browser size...right disappearse:(